# print contents of file - python socket

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to print the contents of a file to the client using the defined command 'get'. I am not getting the contents of the file instead the contents are getting over written with Server Says... get test.txt.

Here is my client code:

```
import socket
import sys
import os

HOST = 'localhost' 
PORT = 8082 
size = 1024

def ls():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
    s.connect((HOST,PORT))
    s.send(userInput)
    result = s.recv(size)
    print result
    s.close()
    return

def put(commandName):
    socket1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket1.connect((HOST, PORT))
    socket1.send(commandName)
    string = commandName.split(' ', 1)
    inputFile = string[1]
    with open(inputFile, 'rb') as file_to_send:
        for data in file_to_send:
            socket1.sendall(data)
    print 'PUT Successful'
    socket1.close()
    return


def get(commandName):
    socket1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket1.connect((HOST, PORT))
    socket1.send(commandName)
    string = commandName.split(' ', 1)
    inputFile = string[1]
    with open(inputFile, 'wb') as file_to_write:
        while True:
            data = socket1.recv(1024)
            print data
            if not data:
                break
            print data
            file_to_write.write(data)
    file_to_write.close()
    print 'GET Successful'
    #socket1.close()
    return

done = False
while not done:
    userInput = raw_input()
    if "quit" == userInput:
        done = True
    elif "ls" == userInput:
       ls()
    else:
        string = userInput.split(' ', 1)
        if (string[0] == 'put'):
            put(userInput)
        elif (string[0] == 'get'):
            get(userInput)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
    s.connect((HOST,PORT))
    s.send(userInput) 
    data = s.recv(size) 
    s.close() 
    print 'Received:', data
```

And server code:

```
import socket
import os
import sys

host = '' 
port = 8082 
backlog = 5 
size = 1024

serverID = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
info = 'SERVER ID: {} port: {}'.format(serverID, port)
print info

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.bind((host,port)) 
s.listen(backlog)
done = False

# Loop until client sends 'quit' to server
while not done: 
    client, address = s.accept() 
    data = client.recv(size)

    print "Server received: ", data
    if data: 
        client.send("Server Says... " + data)
    if data == "quit":
        done = True
    elif data == "ls":
       data = os.listdir("C://")
       client.send(data[0])
    else:
        string = data.split(' ', 1)
        dataFile = string[1]

        if (string[0] == 'put'):
            with open(dataFile, 'wb') as file_to_write:
                while True:
                    data = client.recv(1024)
                    if not data:
                        break
                    file_to_write.write(data)
                    file_to_write.close()
                    break
            print 'Receive Successful'
        elif (string[0] == 'get'):
            with open(dataFile, 'rb') as file_to_send:
                for data in file_to_send:
                    client.send(data)
            print 'Send Successful'

    client.close()
s.close()
print "Server exiting."
```

Comment: You should ask a question ;-)

Comment: @Rbtnk When I do: 
                      for data in file_to_send:
                           client.send(data)                                      it should read the contents of the file and send that data back to the client where    data = socket1.recv(1024) and print data should print whats in the file correct? Sorry, not sure how to format comments.

Comment: It should but not only.  It seems you send your special request as 'get' 2 times.
If I have one advise I would say that you shouldn't open sockets everywhere. Use only one socket in one place for every request. That way you won't have problems like sending 2 times the same request and so.

Comment: I changed this `if not 'Server Says...' in data:
         file_to_write.write(data)`
then i received a text file correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the content of the file but it is empty... and your code works just because you probably run it in the same directory.
Your client open file to write (and then it is empty) and the server reads it (both code use the same file name). You probably wanted to read file from C:\ so you should change server code and replace line:

```
with open(dataFile, 'rb') as file_to_send:
```

with:

```
with open('C:\\' + dataFile, 'rb') as file_to_send:
```

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the problem. Would that be a similar problem in my ls call on the server side?

Comment: I do not think so. ls do not create anything just lists a dir.

Comment: How can I send that list back to the client to print?

Comment: You can for example instead of sending the first element of the list, convert all list to string and send it to client: `client.send(str(data))`

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you send to the server this condition is true so you get "server says..."

```
if data: 
    client.send("Server Says... " + data)
```

You have also several flaws in you client I think. Like your commands are sent 2 times: once in the client 'main' when you do:

```
s.send(userInput)
```

And once in the functions like get and ls :

```
socket1.send(commandName)
```